# Get Assembly code after every optimization GCC makes?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, assembly, compiler-construction

From [Optimization Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) on Wikipedia,

> Compiler optimization is generally implemented using a **sequence of optimizing transformations**, algorithms which take a program and transform it to produce a semantically equivalent output program that uses fewer resources.

and GCC has a [lot](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) of optimization options.

I'd like to study the generated assembly (the one `-S` gives) after each optimization GCC performs when compiling with different flags like `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`, etc.

How can I do this?

Edit: My input will be C code.

Comment: Optimizations are not applied to the assembly code but to intermediate representations.

Comment: To reply to your transient comment, the assembly to which optimization O1 has just been applied before optimization O2 is applied does not exist at any time. If you want to see assembly, all you can do is finish compilation without further optimizations after O1. That may be what you are after, but it's not “the generated assembly […] after each optimization”, which, again, does not exist. Alternately, you may learn how to decipher the intermediate representation, on which you will indeed be able to see the optimizations take effect.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, Yes, that's what I want, sorry I wasn't clear. I want to get ASM output for every state of the IR after an optimization is applied. (I hope I'm getting the terms right.)

Comment: Actually, peephole optimizers DO optimize at that level (assembly/instruction) for optimizations that cannot happen at a generic (non-target specific) IR level.

Comment: -fdump-tree-all should dump intermediate representations.

Comment: @Dogbert Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 9):

**Intermediate representation** can be saved to files using `-fdump-tree-all` switch.

There are more fine-grained `-fdump` switches awailable.

See gcc manual for details.

To be able to read these representations, [take a look into GCC internals manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/).

Comment: Could you give me a link about 'fine-grained -fdump' switches? I search for it but not find.

Comment: here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options. Search for fdump.

Comment: Thank you very much. I searched '-fdump' and '-fdump gcc' and didn't find. Just a char! Thanks again.

Comment: If you search compiler options in google.com, make sure you omit the leading hyphen...

Answer (score 2):

`gcc -S` (**Capital S**)

gives asm output, but the assembler can change things so I prefer to just make an object

`gcc -c -o myfile.o myfile.c`

then disassemble

`objdump -D myfile.o`

Understand that this is not linked so **external branch destinations and other external addresses** will have a placeholder instead of a real number.  If you want to see the optimizations compile with no optimizations (-O0) then compile with -O1 then -O2 and -O3 and see what if anything changes.  There are other optimzation flags as well you can play with.  To see the difference you need to compile with and without the flags and compare the differences yourself.

*diff won't work, you will see why (register allocation changes).*

Comment: I use `objdump -D myfile.o` but it say 'File format not recognized'?

Answer (score 1):

Compile with switch `-S` to get the assembly code. This should work for any level of optimization.
For instance, to get the assembly code generated in `O2` mode, try:

```
    g++/gcc -S -O2 input.cpp
```

a corresponding `input.s` will be generated, which contains the assembly code generated. Repeat this for any optimization level you want.

Comment: Please read the comment I made above on the question. I would like to get the assembly code after every single optimization O2 (for example) performs.

Comment: @Dogbert `-O2` enables a group of *optimization switches*. You can compare the result by turning on and off each. But I'm afraid this is the best you can do. You can't suppress optimization after *each transformation to optimize*. (Basically you can never fully define *each* here. All these methods to optimize are invoked iteratively. Because one optimization may enable aother. So after turning one off, all later optimizations based on that one will be suppressed to.)

Comment: @Dogbert You could, for instance, compile with different flags and compare the output with diff.

Comment: I believe you mean `-S`, not `-s`.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it is possible to take a small piece of code, compile it with `-S` and with a variety of options, the difficulty is understanding what actually changed. It only takes a small change to make code quite different - one variable going into a register means that register is no longer available for something, causing knock-on effects to all of the remaining code in the function.

I was comparing the same code from two nearly identical functions earlier today (to do with a question on C++), and there was ONE difference in the source code. One change in which variable was used for the termination condition inside one for-loop led to over lines of assembler code changing. Because the compiler decided to arrange the registers in a different way, using a different register for one of the main variables, and then everything else changed as a consequence.

I've seen cases where adding a small change to a function moves it from being inlined to not being inlined, which in turn makes big changes to ALL of the code in the program that calls that code.

So, yes, by all means, compile very simple code with different optimisations, and use -S to inspect the compiler generated code. Then compare the different variants to see what effect it has. But unless you are used to reading assembler code, and understand what you are actually looking for, it can often be hard to see the forest for the trees.

It is also worth considering that optimisation steps often work in conjunction - one step allows another step to do its work (inline leads to branch merging, register usage, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

gcc/clang performs optimizations on the intermediate representations (IR), which can be printed after each optimization pass.

for gcc it is (-fdump-tree-all) 'http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html'
with clang it is (-llvm -print-after-all).

Clang/gcc offers many more options to analyze the optimizations. It is easy to turn on/off an optimization from the command line (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html, http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html)

with clang-llvm you can also list the optimization passes which were performed using the command line option (-mllvm -debug-pass=Structure)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to study compiler optimization and are agnostic to the compiler, then take a look at the Clang/LLVM projects.  Clang is a C compiler that can output LLVM IR and LLVM commands can apply specific optimization passes individually.

Output LLVM IR:

```
clang test.c -S -emit-llvm -o test.ll
```

Perform optimization pass:

```
opt test.ll -<optimization_pass> -S -o test_opt.ll
```

Compile to assembly:

```
llc test.ll -o test.s
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution1:

> gcc -O1 -S test.c (the capital O and capital S)

## Solution2:

This [site](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) can also help you. You can use `-O0`, `-O1`, .. whatever suitable *compiler options* to get what you want.

**Example from that site:** (tested by both solutions)

```
 void maxArray(double* x, double* y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
       if (y[i] > x[i]) x[i] = y[i];
    }
 }
```

- Compier Option  `-O0`:

result:

```
maxArray(double*, double*):
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
jmp .L2

.L5:

movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
cltq
leaq    0(,%rax,8), %rdx
movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
addq    %rdx, %rax
movsd   (%rax), %xmm0
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
cltq
leaq    0(,%rax,8), %rdx
movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
addq    %rdx, %rax
movsd   (%rax), %xmm1
ucomisd %xmm1, %xmm0
jbe .L3
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
cltq
leaq    0(,%rax,8), %rdx
movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
addq    %rax, %rdx
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
cltq
leaq    0(,%rax,8), %rcx
movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
addq    %rcx, %rax
movq    (%rax), %rax
movq    %rax, (%rdx)

.L3:

addl    $1, -4(%rbp)

.L2:

cmpl    $65535, -4(%rbp)
jle .L5
popq    %rbp
ret
```

- Compiler Option `-O1`:

result:

```
maxArray(double*, double*):
movl    $0, %eax
.L5:
movsd   (%rsi,%rax), %xmm0
ucomisd (%rdi,%rax), %xmm0
jbe .L2
movsd   %xmm0, (%rdi,%rax)
.L2:
addq    $8, %rax
cmpq    $524288, %rax
jne .L5
rep; ret
```